# viewport meta tag not performing as expected

Tags: html, css, mobile, meta

using this meta tag , as i understand supposed to make the site layout fit itself to a mobile screen width and allow vertical scroll only,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

for some reason it is not performing as expected on my site `http://www.nikib.co.il/`
and im getting a weird behavior

Also tries using

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

But still im not getting the expected results... can anyone think of a reason what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: What do you mean by weird behavior?

Comment: well it is not working as expected. i need the site to fit by its wide to the screen and allow only a scroll up and down

Comment: It's wider than my iPad's screen in portrait orientation (768px). You'll have to make the site narrower to get what you want. Look into media queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your viewport seems to be correct. your CSS isn't. to have the expected behavior you need to adjust your site-width to a maximum of 100% not a fixed pixel-width.

That results in a full code review and partly rebuild of your sites css (and html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```